# Getting IllegalMonitorStateException while printing arraylist using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to print out the content of arraylist using 2 threads, my main goal is to make threads read arraylist in a  synchronized way and print its content. Eventhough I use synchronized block, I still am getting IllegalMonitorStateException. I know this is a basic question but I can not get it working, pardon me.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Q1 {
public static Q1 yeni;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    yeni = new Q1();
}

Q1() {

    List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

    list.add("a1");
    list.add("b1");
    list.add("c1");
    list.add("d1");
    list.add("e1");
    list.add("f1");
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    synchronized (list) {
        myThread thread1 = new myThread(list);
        myThread thread2 = new myThread(list);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

    }
    }

    }
```

And here is myThread class

```
import java.util.*;

public class myThread extends Thread {
List<String> liste;

public myThread(List<String> liste) {
    this.liste = liste;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        synchronized (Q1.yeni) {
            System.out.println("Thread number " + this.getName() + " started running.");
            for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(liste.get(i));
                this.wait(3000);
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Because "current thread is not owner". You can not ```synchronized``` on ```A``` but call ```B#wait``` in  this ```synchronized``` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the `IllegalMonitorStateException` is that you are calling `wait` on an object (`this`) without holding the monitor for that object. You must either wrap this call with a `synchronized (this)` block, or call `wait` on `Q1.yeni`, which this code already has synchronized.

However, it looks like the use of `wait` might be mistaken. This method is used to wait on a condition, which is signaled with a call to `notify` or `notifyAll` on the same object. Since there is no apparent condition in this code, and no usages of `notify` or `notifyAll`, I suspect that what you really want to call is [`this.sleep(3000)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-), which pauses the thread for three seconds, then resumes it after that duration elapses.

The `sleep` method does not require ownership of any monitors, and does not release ownership of held monitors, so another thread would not be able to enter the `synchronized (Q1.yeni)` block while one is currently sleeping. This implies that the first thread to enter that block will run to completion, iterating through the entire list, before the second thread has a chance to begin. It's not totally clear if that's what is intended here.

See the documentation for [`Object.wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) and [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) for more usage information.

A second problem is that `Q1.yeni` is accessed by these threads before it is necessarily initialized, because the threads are started in the `Q1` constructor, and the statement `yeni = new Q1();` only assigns `yeni` after the constructor completes. In this case, it might be better for the threads to use `synchronized (liste)` instead.

Other than that, having `synchronized (list)` in the `Q1` constructor does not accomplish much, since the main thread does not access or manipulate the contents of `list` in that section. The only practical effect is that the threads it starts will block when they reach the first call to `liste.size()` until the main thread exits the `synchronized (list)` (immediately after starting the two threads). This has the potential to slightly slow down the first thread that runs, but has no effect on the thread-safety or correctness of the program.

I would also recommend reviewing ["How to Handle InterruptedException in Java"](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception). In this case, I would recommend restoring the interruption status in the exception handler.

Put together, here is a revised example of this code (including other minor changes to remove unused code and boilerplate comments, improve formatting, and ensure consistency with Java naming conventions):

`Q1.java`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Q1 {
    private static Q1 yeni;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        yeni = new Q1();
    }

    Q1() {
        List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        list.add("a1");
        list.add("b1");
        list.add("c1");
        list.add("d1");
        list.add("e1");
        list.add("f1");

        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(list);
        MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(list);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

`MyThread.java`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final List<String> liste;

    public MyThread(List<String> liste) {
        this.liste = liste;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (liste) {
                System.out.println("Thread number " + this.getName() + " started running.");
                for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(liste.get(i));
                    sleep(3000);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread number Thread-0 started running.
a1
b1
c1
d1
e1
f1
Thread number Thread-1 started running.
a1
b1
c1
d1
e1
f1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering my question. I spent about 2 hours trying to figure out what the problem was. All the sources was redirecting me to use "synchronized (list) block" which I already had and could not figure the problem out. Now I am enlightened, thank you again.

Comment: I’m glad that you found this helpful! The key is to ensure the synchronized block is on the same thread trying to call `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`. If you’re satisfied with this answer, I would appreciate you marking it as accepted. Best of luck!

Comment: I would also recommend following the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) as a way to reinforce understanding of these concepts.